# What is the expected Azure Time-Series-Insights Gen2 API-behavior incase of take-parameter is used for GetEvents and GetSeries endpoints?

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

I am currently experimenting with the Azure TSI Gen2 `ApiVersion = "2020-07-31"` and I am wondering the effect of the `GetSeries` and `GetEvents` endpoints `Take`-parameter.

If I query TSI data for a wide `searchSpan` that contains more events than I define on my `Take`-parameter, what happens? Is the data returned in some order? What is the expected form of the response data?

Documentation definition for the `Take`

> take - integer - Maximum number of property values in the whole response
> set, not the maximum number of property values per page. Defaults to
> 10,000 when not set. Maximum value of take can be 250,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The take parameter specifies the number of events returned by the query (across pages). So if your search span has more events than your "take", TSI randomly selects, or 'takes', that set of records from storage. E.g. if you have 20k events in your search span, and a take of 10k, you'd get a random 10k events from the 20k in that timeframe.

In the TSI explorer, when you "Explore Events" to see the raw data, the explorer calls GetEvents. TSI explorer will always try to show the max (250k) events and will notify you if there more than 250k in the search span.

Data isn't returned in any order by the APIs. Adding sorting capabilities is something we have on our roadmap. Here's a [feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906859-azure-time-series-insights/suggestions/42753125-add-sorting-capabilities-to-getevents-api) where you can upvote the request to add this functionality, as well.

Here's some [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/dataaccessgen2/query/execute#coldstorequerygeteventspage1) showing the request/response of GetEvents and other APIs.

Comment: How does the explorer know there are more events? How can we find that out through the API? Also that feedback link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-query-overview#time-series-query-tsq-apis

**Get Events** and **Get Series** API supports pagination to retrieve the complete response dataset for the selected input.

Comment: I understand paging, however, the take parameter has the following description: `Maximum number of property values in the whole response set, not the maximum number of property values per page. Defaults to 10,000 when not set. Maximum value of take can be 250,000.`

Comment: Source available here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-Time-Series-Insights/blob/master/gen2-sample/csharp-tsi-gen2-sample/DataPlaneClient/Generated/TimeSeriesInsights/DataPlane.TimeSeriesInsights/Generated/Models/GetEvents.cs